# Not in scope: `fromMaybe' - haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

I have a string and a list lst of string  and I should return  nothing if the lst  does not contains the given string  or just list' where list' is identic to the lst except that the first occurene of the given string removed.

```
allExcept :: [Char] -> [[Char]] -> Maybe [[Char]]

allExcept ch1 chars 
   | ch1  `notElem` chars = Nothing

allExcept ch [] = []      
allExcept ch (x:xs)
  | ch /= x = Just(x:(fromJust(allExcept ch xs)))
  | otherwise = Just(xs)
```

the result of my code is : 
                Not in scope: `fromMaybe'

Comment: use the `String` type alias not `[Char]`. also I suspect thr 2nd pattern match is redundant.

Comment: Note that `fromMaybe` is fine, but `fromJust` is dangerous since it is partial: it will crash your program if it is ever applied to `Nothing`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to import the Data.Maybe module:

```
import Data.Maybe
```